# Reindex a specific site as search is not fetching items from there

Tags: 2013, search, blog, index-reset

On Sharepoint 2013, I am using a search web part that is looking into all the blog sites and retrieves the posts. My Search query is this:

```
contentclass:STS_ListItem_Posts and  -Title="Welcome to my blog!" -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople
```

There is a particular Blog Site that is not processed by the search query. So, I am thinking that I should **reindex** (index reset) this site. Do you think that this is a good idea? Is there any chance that reindexing will trigger any alerts on the subscribers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the entire search index? No. Reindex a specific site via the button in site settings? Shouldn't cause any issues.

Also, check the site setting: "allow this site to appear in search results". And, it wouldn't hurt to verify with IT that the account that is used for the crawl has access to the site.

Comment: The account is indeed having access to the site. Shall I make a backup before reindexing this particular site?

Comment: I can never suggest not taking a backup. That's always a good policy, though reindexing shouldn't cause any issues. After all, the account doing the crawl should have read-only access anyway, and shouldn't have the ability to modify anything. Also, there's a decent chance that IT is running a full crawl on some sort of schedule anyway, so this shouldn't be a big issue to do.